# Cannot deserialize value of type when getting CertificateRequest

Tags: fabric8

I am working on fabric8 CertificateRequest, I followed https://github.com/rohankanojia-forks/cert-manager-java-extension-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/io/fabric8/demo/CertificateRequestGet.java to try to get an existing CertificateRequest, but I got error as following.

My test environment:

- Kubernetes Cluster:  OpenShift 4.7.32
- my app environment: Java 11

```
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
IBM Semeru Runtime Certified Edition 11.0.12.0 (build 11.0.12+7)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 11.0.12.0 (build openj9-0.27.0, JRE 11 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210901_134 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 1851b0074
OMR      - 9db1c870d
JCL      - 54d2067eec based on jdk-11.0.12+7)
```

certmanager-client version

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
      <artifactId>certmanager-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Source code

```
        try (CertManagerClient certManagerClient = new DefaultCertManagerClient()) {
            CertificateRequest certificateRequest = certManagerClient.v1()
                .certificateRequests()
                .inNamespace("default")
                .withName("aaaaa")
                .get();

            System.out.println(String.format("%s found in default namespace", certificateRequest.getMetadata().getName()));

            System.out.println(SerializationUtils.dumpAsYaml(certificateRequest));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error:

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:103)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:97)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:263)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:215)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:569)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:527)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:494)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:476)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:788)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:187)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:154)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:87)
    at com.ibm.si.osprey.App.main(App.java:66)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>` from String value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`)
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 1, column: 2603] (through reference chain: io.fabric8.certmanager.api.model.v1.CertificateRequest["status"]->io.fabric8.certmanager.api.model.v1.CertificateRequestStatus["ca"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromString(CollectionDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:250)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3675)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:261)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: seem the issue was caused by deserializing CertificateRequest Status.

Comment: I only see an implementation for  CertificateRequestSpec in the https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/master/extensions/certmanager/model-v1/src/main/java/io/fabric8/certmanager/api/model/v1, but I didn't see CertificateRequestStatus implementation.

Comment: Could you please share your CertificateRequest in YAML format so that we can reproduce?

Comment: Hi Rohan Kumar, please see the bottom yaml file

Comment: Could you please submit an issue on Fabric8 Repository? Looks like this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

this is our outpurt yaml file, for your request.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: CertificateRequest
metadata:
  name: barrycertificaterequest
  namespace: barry
spec:
  duration: 2160h0m0s
  issuerRef:
    group: cert-manager.io
    kind: Issuer
    name: barry-dlc-cert-issuer
  request: >-<here is your csr>
status:
  ca: >-<here is returned ca>
  certificate: >-<here is returned certificate>
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-10-25T20:13:03Z'
      message: Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
      reason: cert-manager.io
      status: 'True'
      type: Approved
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-10-25T20:13:04Z'
      message: Certificate fetched from issuer successfully
      reason: Issued
      status: 'True'
      type: Ready
```

Comment: Hi, I can reproduce this error. This looks like a bug in Fabric8 CertManager Model. In CertificateRequestStatus, `ca` is `List<Integer>` but in go struct it's `[] byte`. I think it should be type String in java class